# Python, SciKit-Learn - How to use `predict_proba()` with missing values ('NaN')

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm running a classification algorithm that uses logistic regression on data that contains missing values (`NaN`).

```
probs = lr_model.predict_proba(data[['var1','var2']])

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

The dataset is oceanic data that is georeferenced in a NetCDF file and the missing values are simply values over land hence no data. Is there a way to run the above code on the ocean data but maintain the position of the NaNs in the dataset so I can later plot the results correctly? Or am I misunderstanding how the `predict_proba` function works?

Comment: Either you can remove examples with NAs or you can put mean or some other preprocessing for that column.

Comment: Hi @SunnysinhSolanki, thanks for your comment. I'm happy with removing the values but I want to be able to preserve their position and put the NaNs back in once I've calculated the probabilities? Otherwise my gridded array won't be correct.

Comment: You won't be able to guess probability by removing 1 value where prediction will be happening with more than 1 future. You'll have to remove those rows where NANs are present. You won't get probabilities for them. If you want probability of rows where some values are NANs then you can put mean of column where NAN is present.

Comment: Thanks @SunnysinhSolanki, I think for now I'll just put in some ludicrous value that makes the probability predicted a 0 and then substitute NaNs back in. Until I have a better method for ignoring these values.

Comment: You can use mean. If you are using pandas dataframe then there is function fillna which you can use to fill NANs.It has parameter called method whose value ffil(forward fill) can be useful to your case.
 If you want to put 0 then use df.fillna(0).

Comment: Thanks @SunnysinhSolanki. Perfect.

Comment: When you trained the model, how did you handle the missing values then?

Comment: @Lachlan.00 : I forgot to inform you last time that Scikit Learn has one pre-processing class called sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer which you can use to fill in NA values with different options.By default, it replaces NANs with mean of feature column.

Comment: Then you should have used the same imputer `transform()`on the testing data.

Comment: You could replace Nans with unique value which is definetely not in existing values of your source/new data. It's common approach. Say, replace Nans to -1.

Comment: Thanks @sergzach, that's the approach I ended up using. I don't think I made it completely clear but these missing values are not important to the dataset and are simply there to help position the array grid correctly (the information is geographical).

Comment: It could be not important (for most classifiers) which special value is in use. Of course you lost information, Nan probably means 'unknown', but you can't escape it - information is unknown indeed.